# SimpleXML deserialize Map<String, String>

Tags: java, dictionary, simple-framework

I have the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<addresses xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='schema_task1_1.xsd'>

  <address>
    <name>Bill</name>
    <city>NewYork</city>
    <street>First</street>
    <phone type='mobile'>+19139130000</phone>
    <documents>
      <document type='driving_permit'>9045798749</document>
      <document type='passport'>3451231231</document>
    </documents>
  </address>

  <address>
    ...
  </address>

</addresses>
```

And the Java classes:

```
@Root(name = "addresses")
public class Addresses {

    @ElementList(inline = true, entry = "address", required = false, type = Address.class)
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();

public class Address {

    @Element(required = false)
    private String name;
    @Element(required = false)
    private String city;
    @Element(required = false)
    private String street;
    @ElementMap(entry = "phone", key = "type", attribute = true, inline = true)
    private Map<String, String> phones;
    @ElementMap(entry = "documents", key = "type", attribute = true, inline = true)
    private Map<String, String> documents = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

All fields deserialize successful, except `documents`. It is always `null` when try to deserialize. I thin I have error in `@ElementMap` annotation, but I don't know what exactly. What am I doing wrong?

PS. I can't change object structure because it is used by another parsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem, but not too nice. If you know better solution, please, let me know.
I just fixed annotation for `document` `Map` and added `uselessVariable` with annotation. It works and doesn't break old code.

UPD. I found better solution. Added `@Path` annotation.

```
@Root(name = "addresses")
public class Addresses {

    @ElementList(inline = true, entry = "address", required = false, type = Address.class)
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();

public class Address {

    @Element(required = false)
    private String name;
    @Element(required = false)
    private String city;
    @Element(required = false)
    private String street;
    @ElementMap(entry = "phone", key = "type", attribute = true, inline = true)
    private Map<String, String> phones;
    @Path("./documents")
    @ElementMap(entry = "document", key = "type", attribute = true, inline = true) //changed this line
    private Map<String, String> documents = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You must create an intermediate class to handle "documents".
This class will contain you map  of "document":

```
class Address {
...
    @Element(required = false)
    private Documents documents;
}
class Documents {
    @ElementMap(entry = "document", key = "type", attribute = true, inline = true)
    private Map<String, String> documents = new HashMap<String, String>();
}
```